# Visual Studio 2022 CMake Error The System cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2022

I have updated the visual studio from 2019 to 2022, and trying to run CMakelists.txt
Ending up with the error "The system cannot find the file specified" for ninja.exe file,
weirdly it's looking for the file in 2019 folder instead of 2022.
I have already tried clearing cache and clean the building directory before I build with visual studio 2022.
Any help/suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!
Here is the screenshot of error:
[image: screenshot of CMake error in visual studio 2022]

[image]

Comment: ninja.exe/ninja.exe at the end of those commands has a pretty strong aroma of a misconfiguration.

Comment: @WhozCraig any suggestion to fix? I don't get the fact it's still looking in 2019 files even after clearing the cache

Comment: I have *neither* (still blessed with using the timeless workhorse, vs2015u3), so I couldn't tell you. Ninja is a cmake generator, so it's probably somewhere in the cmake generator configuration settings on vs2022. vs2015 doesn't support cmake, so I'm relegated to using vscode for my cmake projects (which, honestly, ain't that bad to be completely fair).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting 'out' folder and re creating solved for me